# Maintaining communication with server over mobile network android flutter

Tags: android, flutter, network-programming, android-permissions, background-process

I am trying to write an android app which communicates with a server to query what song to play next after it finishes playing the current song. The idea is that at an outdoor event, people can see the queue and vote songs into it using some frontend webpage, and the songs are then played from my phone connected to some outdoor speaker. Ideally, I would just put my phone down next to the speaker and not have to touch it throughout the event.

I'm having difficulties making the app work continuously and robustly when I am on the battery and using 4G. It works fine in other situations (battery+wifi or when it's plugged in). What happens is that it posts the HTTP requests to the server after playing one or two songs, and then just stops. I cannot figure out what settings I need to enable to make it work seemlessly even with the screen off etc.. My phone runs Android 12.

I tried adding a bunch of permissions in hopes of keeping the mobile network working in the background or for my screen to stay on and maybe that'll keep it working, but to no avail:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

I also tried turning on background data usage for the app, as well as setting its battery usage to "unrestricted" in the settings to avoid the "doze mode" which I found out about, but again none of these mattered. I am not an android developer and have been using AI tools to help me code, so I'm running out of ideas / ways to debug.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
Tusike

Comment: Adding the WAKE_LOCK permission allows you to aquire a wake lock from the power management service.  But you still have to make the calls.  See https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

Comment: Thanks!! this seems to be working, at least it ran fine for the last half an hour! I couldn't find a simple package in flutter to get the partial wake lock (and allow keeping the screen off), maybe I'll have to figure out how to include the native code given in your link to do that. But it is much better than before and might be good enough for now!